# Show Paperclip image in a column Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, paperclip, activeadmin

I can display an images filename in a column within Active Admin but i cannot seem to get the actual image to show

I have a relationship where

```
Member
has_many :member_images

MemberImage
belongs_to :member
```

I can upload an image fine, all associations are in place.

So to show the filename i do

```
column "Filename" do |f|
  f.member_images.map(&:photo_file_name).join("<br />").html_safe
end
```

And i have tried this to show the actual image

```
column "Images" do |m|
  m.member_images do |img|
    image_tag(img.photo.url(:thumb))
  end
end
```

But i get this error in the view

```
<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_MemberImage:0x007f9634a3f760>
```

Can anyone advise what i am doing wrong please

Thank You

EDIT

Have added a .each so i iterate through each image but now i get this displayed

```
[#<MemberImage id: 1, member_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-18 20:28:33", updated_at: "2014-02-18 20:28:33", photo_file_name: "associations.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 140780, photo_updated_at: "2014-02-18 20:28:33">]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try iterate on you images:

```
column "Images" do |m|
  m.member_images.each do |img|
    image_tag(img.photo.url(:thumb))
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you, you are correct, though my output is now [#<MemberImage id: 1, member_id: 1, created_at: "2014-02-18 20:28:33", updated_at: "2014-02-18 20:28:33", photo_file_name: "associations.jpg", photo_content_type: "image/jpeg", photo_file_size: 140780, photo_updated_at: "2014-02-18 20:28:33">]   not the image itself

Comment: @Richlewis try change `each` to `map`.

Comment: ok have tried that, but now i get ["<img alt=\"Thumb\" src=\" link_to_bucket/images/member_images/2/thumb.jpg?1392799208\" />"]

Comment: i never use `paperclip`, but i see right html tag , try open image at `src` link? image available `link_to_bucket/images/member_images/2/thumb.jpg`

Comment: yeah the image is available..I have just found the answer on another post, ill post it here aswell, though i have no idea why this solution works :-)

Comment: just for attempt try add this to my opinion `image_tag(img.photo.url(:thumb)).html_safe` it is works?

Comment: tried html_safe but it did not work..I think its something to do with Active Admin as normally iterating through in the way in your answer would work

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it by add span or other blocks to your image_tag

```
column "Images" do |m|
  m.member_images.each do |img|
    span do
      image_tag(img.photo.url(:thumb))
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking at some other posts with similar issues i can display the image within my column like so

```
column "Images" do |m|
  ul do 
    m.member_images.each do |img|
      li do
        image_tag(img.photo.url(:thumb))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Though I'm not quite sure why this works